# Removing all characters that are not digits in a pandas string type series

Tags: python, regex, pandas, str-replace

From the following pandas series below, I want to remove all characters
 that are not digits.

```
df = pd.series(['0312861','00','66065','6-0io09in4','.314', '3194890809', ':"<>":', '3456.85236', '3465.2154', '312.724146','300.3634865'], index = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11])
```

**numbers**

1. 0312861
2. 00
3. 66065
4. 6-0io09in4
5. .314
6. 3194890809
7. :"<>":
8. 3456.85236
9. 3465.2154
10. 312.724146
11. 300.3634865

For this, I have tried the code:

```
df['numbers'] = df['numbers'].str.replace('\D', '', regex=True)
```

I am expecting the output to be:
**numbers**

1. 0312861
2. 00
3. 66065
4. 6009
5. 314
6. 3194890809
7. Nan
8. 345685236
9. 34652154
10. 312724146
11. 3003634865

However, I am getting the following output:
 **numbers**

1. 0312861
2. 00
3. 66065
4. 60094
5. 314
6. 3194890809
7. Nan
8. Nan
9. Nan
10. Nan
11. Nan

So it seems that my regex takes the last three entries as floating point numbers so it is removing them. However, I want to just remove the period(.) from the last three entries.

I have tried to find my specific solution but did not find it, so i am posting it here in the hope of getting one.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. In other words your code works for me.

Comment: @VorsprungdurchTechnik How can this be possible? Are you sure that you are getting the expected output as I mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

Why you think so complicated when the answer is so simple. Get all characters one by one and check if is digit.

I do not know to work in pandas, but if I was do then I will make a temporary list and then I will try to get just the items of that list and then I will try to get item one by one and then to chek character one by one to see if is digit, and if not then I will pass.

Example:

```
tempList = []

for item in thisList: # thisList will be your list
    tempItem = "" #temporary item
    for character in item:
        # I see you have and some floats there if you want and floats then add that or statement
        if character.isdigit() or character == ".":
            tempItem = f"{tempItem}{character}"
    tempList.append(tempItem)
```

After that I will get a temporary list just with digits items... Yeah that is my stupid answer. Is not an official answer, I was jut try to help.

Comment: Dear @ASI 
Thank you for your response. I appreciate the time and effort you put in answering my request. 

I am not doing it one by one as you said, because I want to avoid using loop as my real dataset is too large i.e over 2 lacks.  So using loop will going to eat up a lot of time. So I guess we need to find some way of doing this task in a faster way.

Comment: Good point. Maybe python will cost to much time because will use just one core of processor, maybe cython will to the trick. What I try to say is maybe c/c++ will make it faster because will use all cores. Maybe multiprocessing will to the trick to because will speed up the power of pure python. I say maybe because I never try it.